# How can I delete all black pixels from an image and only use the unique RGB values found in the image

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, colors, octave

How can I delete all black pixels from an image and only use the unique RGB values found in the image

```
What I'm trying to do is: 
1) delete all black pixels from the image and only use the unique RGB colors found in the image
2) export each combined RGB color pixels that is unique as a separate 640x480 image 
3) Convert / join these images into a movie file.
```

My thoughts where to split my red, green, and blue channels into there corresponding colors and reshape them into three arrays with one column each.
And start deleting the black pixels.

**How can I delete all cell values that are black (where the R,G,B channels are 0) and only find / use the RGB values that are unique**

I've attached the image below and a snippet of the code:

```
resize_tmp_red=reshape(fintersect_red',[1,1200*1200])(:); %will cause array to be created / reshaped left to right and top to bottom (like reading a book) into 1 column
resize_tmp_green=reshape(fintersect_green',[1,1200*1200])(:); 
resize_tmp_blue=reshape(fintersect_blue',[1,1200*1200])(:); 

%How can I delete all cell values that are black (where the R,G,B channels are 0) and only find / use the RGB values that are unique in the image

for cc=1:10

  repmat_rgb(:,:,1)=uint8(repmat(resize_tmp_red(cc,1),[640,480])); %creates 640x480 image of RGB taken from deleted black and unique color array.
  repmat_rgb(:,:,2)=uint8(repmat(resize_tmp_green(cc,1),[640,480]));
  repmat_rgb(:,:,3)=uint8(repmat(resize_tmp_blue(cc,1),[640,480]));

  %imshow(repmat_rgb)


  imwrite(repmat_rgb,strcat('/tmp/',sprintf('%03d', cc),'_img.png')); %creates image file

end
```

PS: I'm using Octave 4.0 which is like Matlab.
And yes I will no longer see the structure of the original image. I will be creating a movie from just the unique colors found in the image.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to replace the black pixels with some other color? Or do you just want an "image" of all the colors which are not black? Note that in the second option, you would no longer see the structure of the original image.

Comment: @Cecilia I just want the colors that are not black and are unique.  Correct I will no longer see the structure of the original image.  I will be creating a movie from just the unique colors found in the image.

Comment: So what is the expected output?  Do you want a 2D matrix of colours perhaps, where each row is a unique RGB colour that isn't black?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes :-)

Comment: Do you want to get rid of zeros in each channel or only (0,0,0)?

Comment: @smttsp I only want to get rid of the color fully black which I believe is only when the  R,G,B channels are (0,0,0)

Comment: @RickT Correct. A black pixel has all channels set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, you would like an output 2D matrix of unique colours where each row is a RGB tuple **without** the black pixels.  What you can do is reshape the RGB image into a 2D matrix where each column is a colour channel, remove all instances where a row is entirely 0, then run it through [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to remove the duplicates.  To do this, you will need to perform a per channel transpose by using [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), then exploiting the order of the elements with [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to finally create a 3 column matrix of RGB values.  Once you do this, use [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) to find all rows that have at least one value (i.e. not a black pixel), filter out the rows of completely zero of your matrix then finally use `unique` but apply this to the rows so that each row would be considered as one "example", given that your image is stored in `im`:

Something like this would work:

```
% Reshape the RGB image into a 3 column matrix
R = reshape(permute(im, [2 1 3]), [], 3);

% Remove black pixels
R = R(any(R, 2), :);

% Remove duplicates
colours = unique(R, 'rows', 'stable');
```

`colours` would be the output 2D matrix of colours that are unique without black.   Note that I've used the `'stable'` flag to maintain the order in which the colours have been encountered.  By leaving this out, it would **sort** the matrix by the rows in the output.  As you have noted in your comment, Octave does not support this functionality so you can remove the `'stable'` flag if you don't care about the order, which I believe you do not in this case as you only want a matrix of unique colours that don't include black.

Therefore:

```
colours = unique(R, 'rows');
```

Comment: nice and elegant solution

Comment: @rayryeng that is a very elegant solution unfortunately Octave 4.0 doesn't seem to work with the `'stable'` option in the line `colours = unique(R, 'rows', 'stable');` is there an alternative for this?

Comment: @RickT Yes, you can remove `'stable'`.  I just had it there to ensure the order of colours is enforced. If you don't care about the order... (which I think you don't), remove the `'stable'`.  You just want a list of colours and I'm assuming you don't care about the order?

Comment: @RickT See my question in my previous comment.

Comment: @RickT No worries. Thank you for accepting. I've also edited my post to remove the `'stable'` flag as it isn't supported in Octave right now.  That's a shame.

Answer (score 2):

To find the black pixels, you simply want all three color channels to be zero. You can tell the `sum` function to sum across the third dimension. If all three channels are zero, the sum is also zero.

```
im = imread('example.png');    
black_mask = sum(im, 3) == 0;
```

Now you have a 2d mask indicating the black pixels. The next step is to construct masks to access all other pixels in each channel

```
red_mask = ~cat(3, black_mask, ones(size(black_mask)), ones(size(black_mask)))); %The inverse of the black mask in the red channel and any pixel in all other channels
green_mask = ~cat(3, ones(size(black_mask)), black_mask, ones(size(black_mask))));%For the other channels just change the order.
blue_mask= ~cat(3, ones(size(black_mask)), ones(size(black_mask)), black_mask));
```

Okay, now we can grab the values from each channel.

```
red = im(red_mask);
blue = im(blue_mask);
green = im(green_mask);
```

And concatenate them in the third dimension to make an image

```
non_unique = cat(3, red, green, blue);
```

`non_unique` is an image containing all the non-black pixels. To get unique pixels, you have to permute the matrix to use `unique`'s 'row' option.

```
non_unique = permute(non_unique, [1 3 2]);
output = unique(non_unique, 'rows'); %Get unique rows
output = permute(output, [1 3 2]); %Permute it back to recover color channels
```

The output image is 1 pixel width and 94 pixels long. To get your desired 640x480 shape you will need to reshape and resize it. I couldn't find any good factors to get the desired ratio, so I just used the largest prime factors of 94: 2 and 47.

```
reshaped_output = reshape(output, 2, 47, 3);
reshaped_output = imresize(reshaped_output, [480, 640]);
```

Here's a comparison of the image at various steps.

[image: Subplots showing all non-black pixels, unique non-black pixels, and final reshaped image]

Comment: This doesn't find the unique colors, this just removes the zeros and converts 3D to 2D. Also `output = [red, green, blue]` instead of `cat`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way but you can do this:

```
R = double(im(:,:,1))*255*255;
G = double(im(:,:,2))*255;
B = double(im(:,:,3));
RGB = R+G+B; % Now you have 2D matrix

unq = sort(unique(RGB));
unq = unq(2:end); %remove (0,0,0)

B2 = rem(unq(:),255);
G2 = rem((unq-B2)/255,255);
R2 = (unq-G2*255 - B2)/255/255;
% You can make this part more efficient probably. and make sure there is no error

colors_you_want = [R2 G2 B2];
```

What I did is, I converted the 3D image to a 2D double matrix and find all the unique elements which is all the colors you want. The first element of `unq` is (0,0,0), so I removed that one. Then I converted back to a 2D structure where R is the first column, G is the second and B is the third column.

Answer (score -2):

I don't use the language you have put in your code, but if I were doing this in c/c++ I would loop through the data and count the non-black pixels, create a new array of that size, and loop through again and copy them one by one into the new array. Can this be done?

Comment: Matlab/Octave has better ways of doing this, not requiring loops.

Comment: Even if you do with c++, why do you need to loop through twice, why not simply use a vector which can be expanded?

Comment: Giving answers in a language that isn't part of the tags is usually not helpful.